# htaccess rewrite not working for one of the cases

Tags: apache, .htaccess

below specific redirect rules are not working properly for my website

```
 RewriteRule ^/?deal\/([а-я\-0-9A-Я]+)\/(\d+)    index.php?menu=details&id=$2 [L]

 RewriteRule ^/?coupon\/([а-я\-0-9A-Я]+)\/(\d+)  index.php?menu=details&id=$2 [L]
```

rest redirects are fine? what can be the issue?

One of the links that gives not found is below

http://dealschintu.com/coupon/2009

Answer (score 0):

Your URL and pattern are different. Try these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^deal/(\d+)/?$ index.php?menu=details&id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^coupon/(\d+)/?$ index.php?menu=details&id=$1 [L,QSA]
```